# conditional redirect in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to do a conditional redirect in my routes file.

Users can opt to have a shorter url for their site. When this short url is available but the longer url is used, I always want to redirect them to the shorter version. For example: user goes fubar.mysite.com but fubarsite.com is available -> redirect from fubar.mysite.com to fubarsite.com .

I store the available shorter url in the database.

I want to do this in routes but don't know if this is possible. I tried the constraint approach but have no idea how to do the redirect in the block

```
constraints(Redirect) do
 #need to redirect here
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should not do this in your routes file because it involves a lot of logic. Maybe you want to setup a `before_filter` in your application controller and do the check there. If the shorter url is available then do the redirect. You'll need a sort of catch all route in your routes file for doing that.

Comment: Thats how I do it now but I hoped that I could move this to the routes file. thanks for the answer

Comment: @Tarscher redirections belong to the controller part of you app, the routes file is just a map from paths to controllers. IMHO the right place where to do the redirect IS the controller.